# Image and Text side by side

Tags: image, text

As you can see in the screenshot I have attached, I am not able to make this post list in responsive mode.
I don’t know but somehow it is showing image in mobiles as in attached screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a minimal CSS framework, which helps you position your objects through a grid. There are many of those frameworks, but i suggest you check out [miniCSS](https://miniCSS.org), [iota](http://korywakefield.com/iota/) or [chota](https://jenil.github.io/chota/#!) for a start.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response. Now I am a newbie so, I don’t know what minimal css is. One more thing I want to know is if I use minimal CSS then can I implement this HTML code to Wordpress?

Comment: May i ask you to please rephrase the question, so it is clear what you are asking? Also, there is a dedicated [wordpress stack exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Okay, I am a newbie and I don’t know that much of coding so I use Wordpress to build a website. Now what I am trying to do here is I want to show some of the latest and recent post on my home page in a list view(e.g. Image should be on left side and text on right side). So, I build the above code to show my post in a list view from w3school. Now the problem is after applying this code on Wordpress it looks good in desktop and tablet. But, When I see in mobile it looks as shown in attached screenshot. So, we can say it is not responsive as it should be in all device.